# Match non-latin letters

Tags: mysql, regex

I try to write a query filtering rows containing non-latin letters.

Unfortunately my valid characters contain latin letters, latin accented letters, special characters (.+$%...) numbers, space ..., so it's not easy to collect all of them

I tried to construct my groupings based on UTF-8 table (https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) however it doesn't work as expected:

- basic latin block spans from `space` to `ÿ`, so I tried
  `not RLIKE "^[ -ÿ]+$"` (filter entries not containing only allowed characters from beginning to end)
  however I got error "*SQL Error [1139] [42000]: Got error 'invalid character range' from regexp*"
  same for `[!-ÿ]` too
  trying the same in https://regex101.com/ works correctly
- next I tried to split range and used:
  `not RLIKE "^[ !-zÀ-ü]+$"`
  it works without an error, however it drops only entries with Chinese characters as invalid, and it ignores all cyrillic characters.
  Seems `À-ü` range contains cyrillic characters for MySQL 5.7

What character mapping MySQL 5.7 is using? How I can distinguish latin and non-latin letters?

---

Edit: I found out my encoding is utf8mb4, however I still don't know how I could solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.7 has one set of REGEXP rules.  The real deficiency is that it works only with bytes.  Hence your test for Chinese/Cyrillic/etc is doomed to fail.  8.0 is a major rewrite and has a chance of letting your regexps work.

The Unicode standards group keeps issuing new standards.  MySQL has adopted 4.0, 5.20 and 9.0 in different collations.

You say you want to exclude all non-Latin characters.  Do you really mean to *include* these:

```
+--------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| utf8a  | utf8z  | meaning                                                                                  |
+--------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 41     | 5A     | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A .. LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z                                         |
| 61     | 7A     | LATIN SMALL LETTER A .. LATIN SMALL LETTER Z                                             |
| C380   | C396   | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE .. LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS               |
| C398   | C3B6   | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE .. LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS                |
| C3B8   | CAB8   | LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE .. MODIFIER LETTER SMALL Y                              |
| E1B880 | E1BEBC | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING BELOW .. GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA WITH PROSGEGRAMMENI |
| E281B1 | E281B1 | SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER I .. SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER I                     |
| E281BF | E281BF | SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N .. SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N                     |
| EFBCA1 | EFBCBA | FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A .. FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z                     |
| EFBD81 | EFBD9A | FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER A .. FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER Z                         |
+--------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Apparently that is not quite what you want punctuation.

You want "space" -- these are considered "white space", do you want all of them?

```
+----------+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
| hex_utf8 | name                      | category | decomposition  |
+----------+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
| 0C       | <control>                 | Cc       | NULL           |
| 20       | SPACE                     | Zs       | NULL           |
| E19A80   | OGHAM SPACE MARK          | Zs       | NULL           |
| E1A08E   | MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR | Zs       | NULL           |
| E28080   | EN QUAD                   | Zs       | 2002           |
| E28081   | EM QUAD                   | Zs       | 2003           |
| E28082   | EN SPACE                  | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E28083   | EM SPACE                  | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E28084   | THREE-PER-EM SPACE        | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E28085   | FOUR-PER-EM SPACE         | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E28086   | SIX-PER-EM SPACE          | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E28087   | FIGURE SPACE              | Zs       | <noBreak> 0020 |
| E28088   | PUNCTUATION SPACE         | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E28089   | THIN SPACE                | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E2808A   | HAIR SPACE                | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E280A8   | LINE SEPARATOR            | Zl       | NULL           |
| E2819F   | MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE | Zs       | <compat> 0020  |
| E38080   | IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE         | Zs       | <wide> 0020    |
+----------+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
```

Please tighten up your question; then I may be able to help you.

Here's a taste of *one* direction to go.  This will check for Cyrillic in a string:

```
SELECT HEX('яростных') REGEXP '^(..)*D[0-4]';
```

(That works with 8.0 and before 8.0.)

Maybe all you want is this (for catching non-latin characters)?

```
WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)([89ABDEF]|C[0-24-9A-F])'
```

(All that said here applies to `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `utf8mb4`.)

Comment: Thanks! `HEX` did the job, with that I can now refine your expression to fit my need.

Comment: "You say you want to exclude all non-Latin characters" - my main concern now are non-latin letters, whether other characters of non-latin sets are included is less of a concern (i.e. I can live with an expression w/o filtering them)